# Assembler messages: no such instruction xbegin

Tags: assembly, clang, llvm

I'm building a set of tools based on a unification-based alias analysis using llvm-3.4, gcc-4.8.
I got a serials of errors indicating: 
"assembler messages: no such instruction: xbegin, xend, xabort, etc. "
The os is ubuntu server 12.04.

Any idea about what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Those are TSX instructions, but I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are pseudo-instructions that are not standard for all assemblers.

I know that they are used under MacOS but typically not under Linux.

Maybe you cannot compile the code under Linux.

Comment: I switched to ubuntu server 13.10 and no similar problem ever appeared. still don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your code with the GCC option `-mrtm`.

Comment: That affects whether the intrinsics are allowed in C/C++.  This question is about the assembler not even recognizing the asm instructions, which doesn't depend on compiler options.  (Use `gcc -v` to see the compiler/assembler/linker command lines, and notice that `-march=skylake` or `-mrtm` don't add extra options to the assembler command line).

Comment: I meet with same problem, my gcc version is 5.3.0 on Redhat 7.1. The error is "error: no such instruction, 'xbegin .L52'".

Comment: TSX only works on Skylake and some late Broadwell CPUs.  Intel had to disable it with a microcode update for Haswell after discovering a bug: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions